# CMakeLists - how to recursively delete directories

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

How can I have cmake recursively delete directories, equivalent to `rm -rf`?

I have tried using [file(REMOVE_RECURSE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem)  which sounds like the right thing but I found that `file(REMOVE_RECURSE test/)`  will delete a directory called `test` if `test` is empty or contains files or empty directories. However, if `test` contains another directory which contains a file, nothing is deleted - it is silently ignored.

```
cmake version 3.18.4
```

Comment: hm. this behaviour seems inconsistent with the documentation. I'm on cmake 3.24 and created a file `d` in folder `a/b/c` in the source directory, and can do `file(REMOVE_RECURSE a)`, and it will remove all of a, b, c, and d. It also does this if I put a trailing slash after `a` like `a/`. Can you make a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

I found the same with `cmake 3.17.5`.

My fix was to specify the full path, as in:

```
file(REMOVE_RECURSE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test/)
```